# Silmarillion & Book of Lost Tales, which should I read first?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, suggested-order

Several years back I read *The Hobbit* and *Lord of the Rings*.

I recently discovered (when going through some old boxes I hadn't unpacked after moving house) that I've got a few additional books which I've never read, mainly *The Silmarillion* and *The Book of Lost Tales Pt. 1 + 2*.

Is there any order to these? Which should I read first? Or doesn't it matter?

Comment: Those are all very good clear answers. I would def agree with reading the Silmarillion first, unfinished tales second followed by lost tales. Encyclopedia of arda or tolkein gateway are essentials as mentioned.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I asked a similar, more general question <s>on Literature.SE</s> about the [reading order of all of Tolkien's works](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15534/in-what-order-should-tolkiens-writings-on-middle-earth-be-read). The consensus was that *The Silmarillion* should come before the less mature *HoME*. *The Silmarillion* is a few well-developed stories about the First Age, while *The Book of Lost Tales* is a collection of story fragments and edited notes covering some of the same content. By reading *The Silmarillion* first you will have a better understanding of the history as Tolkien intended us to read it (though even *The Silmarillion* was not complete at the time of his death), then you can go back to *Lost Tales* and see how the stories developed from earlier notes.

Comment: Thanks for this, I had never thought about the literature site ...

Comment: That question is now here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15534/in-what-order-should-tolkiens-writings-on-middle-earth-be-read

Comment: @Wade And mine is now a duplicate of one that didn't exist when I wrote it.

Comment: @takrl And mine is now migrated from a site that exists again where it would still be on topic. What a tangled interweb we weave.

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend reading *The Silmarillion* first. That's the order of publication, and *The Book of Lost Tales* contains only fragments of stories that will act as spoilers for the more coherent story contained in *The Silmarillion*.

Answer (score 6):

I'd agree that you should read *The Silmarillion* first, but would just add that you should probably read *Unfinished Tales* next, before the two BoLT volumes. UT includes additional versions of several of the stories from the Silmarillion, as well as a whole lot of extra information about Tolkien's world (including who the Wizards really were).

Comment: Strongly Agree -- Unfinished Tales should be considered HOME vol 0. Read it before any of the Official HOME books.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the order everyone suggests, if you've never read the lorebooks, I would suggest you have a browser handy with the [Encyclopedia of Arda](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/lexicon.html) on it...because you likely WILL get lost in the names and details.

Comment: Two bookmarks: one in the text, and one in the index, will generally work just as well. The index in *The Silmarillion* is really good, and also includes a little potted biography or description with all the entries.