# In what order should Tolkien's writings on Middle-earth be read?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, suggested-order

I've already read *The Hobbit* and *The Lord of the Rings*, which I assume would be the best start in any case. I also got about halfway through *The Silmarillion* several years ago and am quite familiar with the legendarium as a whole, but for the sake of argument let's assume I'm starting from scratch.

What is the best order for a budding scholar of Middle-earth to read Tolkien's books? Or does it even matter once you've covered the core novels? Chronological order clearly isn't the most logical approach here, and even publication date isn't necessarily best.

- The Hobbit
- The Lord of the Rings
- The Silmarillion
- The Children of Hurin
- The History of Middle-earth
- Unfinished Tales
- The Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien
- Anything else

**Note:** After asking this question I found [this excellent reference](http://www.reddit.com/r/lotr/comments/151jct/recommended_reading_for_tolkien_fans/) on Reddit. It covers even more material and in more detail than my original question or any answers here.

Comment: "Should" and "best" indicate opinion-based questions with primarily opinion-based answers. Please clarify whether you're looking for the most chronological, published order, or the order in which information is revealed (i.e. reading LoTR before the Hobbit is ill advised because LoTR assumes that the reader is familiar with the Ring's origin).

Comment: It is enough just to read them.
Do not be overly concerned about finding 'a reading order' You would be ill advised to take Tolkien's Writings on Middle Earth so seriously that you worry about such things.
Read for yourself. when YOU want, How YOU want, IF YOU WANT, & At YOUR own speed.

Comment: From the front of the book to the back, and from the upper left to the lower right.

Comment: Too late for the OP, but I highly recommend reading these to your (young) children, so they can experience them as I did...as a sort of mish-mash of legends and stories half-remembered from early childhood, reinforced when I finally read them for myself - in published order.

Comment: I would consider adding some of his non-Middle Earth short stories, especially "Smith of Wooton Major", after you finish LOTR and the Hobbit. That particular story added a lot of depth to Tolkien's way of thinking (to me) that really enriched my reading of the Silmarillion.

Comment: I would read *Unfinished Tales* immediately after reading *The Silmarillion*. The former fills in some of the blanks of the latter (along with some blanks from *The Hobbit* and *LotR*).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I believe publication order is the best way, you will experience the reading experience that helped to shape Middl-earth. Although Tolkien left **many** manuscripts that later became successful books, his central piece is *The Lord of the Rings*. The Hobbit is a preamble and everything that follows are great efforts to close the circle of his creations in a consistent way.

I read *The Lord of the Rings* first, and got bored easily with *The Hobbit*, I loved *The Silmarillion* but I had to dig through The History of Middle-earth to find pearls that somehow were not included (like the Battle of Gondolin and the death of Glorfindel).

Follow what Tolkien wanted you to know, then discover what he didn't have time to publish and when you are done with that start learning that Middle-earth is the result of Tolkien's brilliance and many revisions and rewrites... and that Aragorn once was a Hobbit and Treebeard was evil :)

Comment: "Aragorn once was a Hobbit" -- news to me. How is that even possible?

Comment: It says it's a rewrite. It doesn't exist, it's what could have been. I much prefer Aragorn as a Dunedain human though.

Comment: @Scribblemacher The *character* of Strider (who was later changed to subsume Aragorn) was originally *Trotter*, a relation of Frodo's (Frodo was also formerly called Bungo), thus, a Hobbit.

Comment: and Treebead was an evil _giant_ (not tree) :-)

Comment: You should read _The Hobbit_, if at all possible, when you're 11.

Comment: The problem with this (otherwise great) answer is that it doesn't include *The Children of Húrin* (and other works that were published since it was written).

Comment: I read Tolkien wrote the LTR series as warm up exercises on descriptive writing in preparation for The Hobbit.

Comment: @ATL_DEV what is "LTR"?

Comment: @DavidRoberts  I was taught to not capitalize insignificant words in the title such as *of*, *the*, etc. I figured the same rule carries over to acronyms of titles. I guess I'm wrong since English conventions are based on class, status and majority, not logic.

Comment: @ATL_DEV I'm genuinely mystified. What does your acronym mean? It can't mean Lord of the Rings, since that was published 17-18 years after the Hobbit, and its writing process is well-documented: it was started after the Silmarillion material was rejected for publication, which was after the Hobbit was published and was a commercial success.

Comment: @AlfredoHernández - "Middl-earth"???

Answer (score 75):

I would recommend this order:

- The Hobbit
- The Lord of the Rings

  (stop here)
- The Silmarillion

  (stop here)
- The Children of Húrin
- Beren and Lúthien
- The Fall of Gondolin

  (stop here)
- Unfinished Tales
- The Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien

  (stop here)
- The History of Middle-Earth
- The Nature of Middle-Earth
- The Annotated Hobbit (Douglas A. Anderson)
- The History of the Hobbit (John D. Rateliff)

*The Lord of the Rings* presumes that you have read *The Hobbit*. (You may very well be able to get away without reading it, but there are clear back-references.)

*The Silmarillion* does not presume that you have read *The Lord of the Rings*, but would probably not be interesting to someone who is not already invested in Middle-earth.

The *Great Tales* trilogy are stories from *The Silmarillion* in more detailed forms. They require an understanding of the First Age stories to appreciate.
*The Children of Húrin* is a complete and detailed version of that story. *Beren and Lúthien* and *The Fall of Gondolin* are collections of the varying versions of those tales, stitched together in a directly readable order. All three of these contain significant amounts of re-printed text from *The Unfinished Tales* and *The History of Middle-earth*. These books are written to present that material in a smoother, more entertainment oriented fashion, rather than the dryer and more academic tome of the other versions.

*The Unfinished Tales* are exactly what it says on the tin. They contain some of Christopher Tolkien's notes about the source of the text, but are mostly readable as stories. Familiarity with *The Silmarillion* is essential here.

*The Letters of Tolkien* is a very interesting read, and could really be read almost anywhere in series. It is not, of course, a story.

You should not read *The History of Middle-Earth* unless you are totally fanatic. It is not a series of stories, but an extended discussion of the writing of *The Silmarillion*, *The Lord of the Rings*, and some ancillary works. If you do read it, you will want to use two bookmarks, one for the primary text, and one for the copious footnotes that follow. Expect large chunks of any story you might get into reading to be removed, and replaced with a reference to *The Silmarillion*, *The Unfinished Tales*, or an earlier volume of the series. *The History* should be read in volume order, as later volumes make references to earlier ones. (If you only care about *The Lord of the Rings*, you could just read volumes 6-9. If you do, consider replacing Volume 9, *Sauron Defeated* with *The End of the Third Age*, which includes only the parts of that book that deal with *The Lord of the Rings*.) *The Nature of Middle-Earth* could be considered a 13th volume of the *History*, assembling some works published elsewhere with a series of other notes and variants.

If you make it through *The History of Middle-earth*, you might as well read *The History of the Hobbit*. Christopher Tolkien basically skipped over *The Hobbit* in the main history. John D. Rateliff takes over as the chronicler, doing an excellent job of examining the evolution of *The Hobbit*, and how it tied into the emerging legendarium. It makes a lot of references to *The History of Middle-earth*, so familiarity with that is necessary. It does not go into detail on the 1965 revisions to the hobbit, so it's recommended that you pair this with *The Annotated Hobbit* (Douglas A. Anderson.) to get the full, blow-by-blow evolution of the text.

Comment: Shouldn't I read The Children of Hurin after Silmarilion after that the Hobit and LOTR? To me it makes sense to start from the begining?

Comment: I really like this answer.  The "stop here" points are great for identifying places where - if you've already gotten what you want from the books - you can just quit reading safe in the knowledge that you're not going miss anything that's important to you.  I read Hobbit/Silm/LotR by the way, but I wouldn't recommend *that* to anyone!

Comment: One hint for if you want to go on to the Silmarillion and Histories is if you read and really liked the Appendices in LOTR.  If you skipped them, or were bored by them, you won't like the rest almost for sure.

Comment: @Oldcat - With the possible exception of Children of Hurin and select parts of UT and HoME.

Comment: Looks like we'll have to add the Fall of Gondolin soon! I wonder where this book would fall in the reading order...

Comment: I suspect _Fall of Gondolin_ will fall after _Beren and Luthien_, if it is made similarly.

Comment: "Beren and Lúthien and The Fall of Gondolin are collections of the varying versions of those tales, stitched together in a directly readable order" - are you sure about this? From what I've read in other answers, these books are more like the *History* than *The Children of Húrin*, and aren't really "smoother, more entertainment oriented"...

Comment: From what I've heard, *Unfinished Tales* is the easier read, so perhaps it should be recommended to read before these two...

Comment: I'd say that Beren and Lúthien and The Fall of Gondolin are smoother and more entertainment oriented than The History of Middle-earth, but they're far less successful than The Children of Húrin at accomplishing that.

Comment: Is there a chance you might specify a suggested order for the volumes of HoMe?

Comment: I've made an edit to that effect. In short, read HoME in its own order by volume number.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. Do you need to read the History of the Lord of the Rings in order to read volumes 10-12 (and parts 2-3 of volume 9), though? It seems to me that they deal with writings of the first (and maybe 2nd) age, so it surprises to me they'd make references to volume 6-8.

Comment: You _could_ skip 6-8 if you just don't care, I guess. Volumes 10 and 11 contain revisions to _The Silmarillion_ that were made after _The Lord of the Rings_ was published, so they mostly care about the _as published_ text. I wouldn't want to make the claim for every footnote.

Comment: You didn't list _The Book of Lost Tales_, which was the first thing I read after _The Silmarillion_ so long ago. It's one of the first things he wrote!

Comment: _The Book of Lost Tales_ is the first two volumes of _The History of Middle Earth_.

Answer (score 25):

The Tolkien Society's recommendations can be found [here](http://www.tolkiensociety.org/faq01.html#order):

> The order is The Hobbit, The Lord of the Rings, [The Adventures of Tom Bombadil if you wish to read the poems], The Silmarillion and Unfinished Tales (you can swap those two over if you want to read the longer Numenor tales before the whole history of The Silmarillion) and then the Histories.

Answer (score 4):

The order in which I actually read them is, I think, quite excellent:

1. The Hobbit
2. The Lord of the Rings (including the Appendices)
3. The Silmarillion
4. The Adventures of Tom Bombadil
5. Unfinished Tales
6. The Road Goes Ever On
7. Pictures by J.R.R. Tolkien
8. The History of Middle-earth (12 volumes, in the order of their publication dates)
9. The Children of Hurin
10. The two-volume History of The Hobbit

If it helps, I started reading The History of Middle-earth in 1991, when Christopher Tolkien was still immersed in completing the volumes on the history of The Lord of the Rings.

Comment: NB: I don't remember when I first read The Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien, but it was probably when I was in the process of reading the early volumes of The History of Middle-earth.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Could you expand a bit on this answer to explain _why_ you think this is a good order to read them in?

Comment: It's so cool Christopher jumped right into his dad's boots and continued his legacy. It's common for children of notable individuals to have difficulty living under the shadow of their parent's work, seeking instead to create name for themselves in other areas.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want it to be in order of the history,  instead of publications.

Here it is:

- Silmarillion
- Children of Hurin
- Unfinished tales
- The Hobbit
- Lord of the Rings

The problem with this order is that if you dont know middle earth well then you may struggle reading the order above. Because Silmarillion, Hurin and Unfinished tales are all complex.

But you can read the books in the order below,  if you want to learn about middle earth, or if you are a beginner or just starting to get into Tolkien's books.

- The hobbit
- Lord of the rings
- Silmarillion
- Children of Hurin
- Unfinished tales
- History of Middle Earth

You can read also the letter's of J.R.R Tolkien if you want. These are not a story just a collection of letters by J.R.R Tolkien to some people.

Answer (score 0):

The order in which I have been reading them:

- *The Lord of the Rings*
- *The Hobbit*
- *The Silmarillion*
- *Unfinished Tales*

Next, I plan to read the volumes of *The History of Middle-earth* related to LotR, then the rest of that series.  After that, I will probably read *The Adventures of Tom Bombadil*, then *The Children of Hurin*. I have *The Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien* on my iPad, and I've been using them to answer questions here, but I'll eventually buy a hard copy and read it cover to cover.

I would recommend the following order:

- *The Hobbit*
- *The Lord of the Rings*
- *The Silmarillion*
- Whatever you want.

Once you get a good feel for these books, which are the core of the material, you'll be able to decide how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

The most proper order according to me which would make history of Middle Earth would be to go backwards. By following this way of enhancing your knowledge of Arda, you would enjoy it and never get bored.
1) The Hobbit
2) The Lord of the Rings
3) Silmarillion
4) Unfinished Tales
5) Children of Hurin(I consider it rather optional as many details regarding it are already given in the previous two books)
6) Adventures of Tom Bombadil(if you love reading poems)
7) The History of Middle Earth(3 VOLUMES)

You would love reading books of Tolkien this way.