# In what order should I read the Dragonlance trilogies?

Tags: books, suggested-order, dragonlance

Recently I have finished the Chronicles trilogy by Margaret Wise and Tracy Hickman. I tried to find the Trilogy that comes after Chronicles, but the library didn't know.

What is the correct reading order of the Dragonlance trilogies?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're asking about the Dragonlance books, which in fairness are based on DnD. I edited to be more specific, but feel free to make changes if I got something wrong

Comment: Oh my bad lmao thank you

Comment: http://www.dlnexus.com/products/reading.aspx

Comment: http://www.angelfire.com/folk/native_son/DL/

Comment: [From the front of the book to the back, and from the upper left to the lower right.](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15534/in-what-order-should-tolkiens-writings-on-middle-earth-be-read/15536#comment224990_15534)