# Do you really need to read “The Silmarillion” before reading “The Children of Húrin”, “Beren and Lúthien” or “The Fall of Gondolin”?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, suggested-order, the-silmarillion

The answer to the question [In what order should Tolkien's writings on Middle-earth be read?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15534/in-what-order-should-tolkiens-writings-on-middle-earth-be-read) suggests that you should read *The Silmarillion* and only then go on to read the three "great tales", which are *The Children of Húrin*, *Beren and Lúthien* or *The Fall of Gondolin*.

**But is it really important to read *The Silmarillion* before you read *The Children of Húrin*, *Beren and Lúthien* and/or *The Fall of Gondolin*? How much will I miss if I skip *The Silmarillion*?**

I'm thinking both about plot elements that I will not understand because I don't have the necessary background, as well as things that I will fail to appreciate because I don't understand their full impact...

Comment: When you get down to it, it's not necessary to read any of them.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron Do you mean to say that they're boring?

Comment: [Related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/247659/what-to-read-in-history-of-middle-earth).

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Not really related. The book *The Children of Hurin* is mentioned only in passing, in one of the answers, and the issue I raised is not addressed or even mentioned. The other two books are not mentioned at all.

Comment: If you read Silmarilion and Unfinished Tales, these three are just synthesizing and elaborating what's already told, so, not particularly necessary.

Comment: Whether it's necessary depends on the goal. If you only need the broad story, of course you can skip them all and read maybe one to three wiki pages instead. Why bother with the books, unless you find Tolkien's works themselves worth your time reading? I had to read them in the order they were published, so I don't know whether the background history will bother you if you skip Silm. But you can always read only the background history in Silm., skip the three corresponding Chapters and read the separate books.

Comment: @Mithoron Are you sure about that? I think the majority of these three books come from the History of the Middle-Earth, doesn't it?

Comment: @Wade Well, at least "Children..." do that.

Comment: I've been tempted before, to ask the question, "Has anyone actually read the *entire* Silmarillion"? :) I mean, I like it, but there are a couple of chapters in the middle, where my eyes really glaze over. "Then Hurindorthingol, the great-great-great-grandson of Hurin, went to war with Finwemandorthin, the great-great-nephew of Fingol, who lived in the the neighboring hut, on the claims that he had stolen his pig, and therefore he called his entire clan of the great-great-great-grandchildren of Hurin, and Durin, and Balin, to go to *war*".

Comment: @JohnC hahaha... I know what you mean. I never managed to read more than a few pages. That's why I was hoping to avoid it before going on to more coherent tales... It seems it is possible at least with The Children of Hurin, although probably not with the other two ):

Comment: @Wade  Tsk, tsk.  I have read a lot of history books and have enjoyed them.  And of course the closer those history books stuck to the facts, the less they had plots with beginnings, middles, and ends, or with protagonists and antogonists.  I have also read translations of various epics like the Iliad and Beowulf.  And I have read translations of various books perporting to give the history of various lands and peoples from mythical times to legendary to semi historical times to fully historical times, like Geoffrey of Monmouth's HIstory of the KIngs of Britain, or...  Continued

Comment: @Wade   Continued  ...or Snorri Sturluson's Heimskringla, or Ferdowsi's Shahnamah.  So naturally I just loved the Sillmarillion.  I guess there must be something wrong with my reading taste if I enjoy stuff that other people find too difficult or too boring.

Comment: @M.A.Golding What have I said to make you think that I think there's something wrong with that? I was just asking how bad it'd be if I skipped the Silmarilion, since I didn't like it so far

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Not really even related. None of the four books in this question overlap with the twelve books in that question. Also this one is asking about reading order (Does X need to be read before Y) and the other is asking about reading advice (Which items of X,Y, and Z are worth reading).

Comment: @Wade - Silm *does* get better once you get about a third of the way into it. And the last half of the book is all narrative.

Comment: @ibid I'll keep that in mind. I think you convinced me to go CoH, then UT and Silm (in either order), and then B&L and FoG.

Comment: weighing in as a light reader.  I may not forgive my father for gifting me the Silmarillion at age 10.  It crushed my spirit at an early age.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll be the contrarian here: For *Children of Húrin*, which stands on its own as a (short) book, I suggest reading it *before* reading *The Silmarillion*.

Yes, of course there is a lot of context you would be missing. But I believe that it makes the book more magical and exciting to read - full of actual mystery, rather than being, well, a novelization of some piece of history that you already know. Having read *The Silmarillion*, you know who is going to go where, meet whom, do what, and die when. The book is still nice, but it's nowhere as near as engaging an experience as reading it without all that background.

Then when you read *The Silmarillion* you'll have some throwback to the stories you read in the book.

For the other two... @ibid is probably right.

Comment: To support this, it's noteworthy that *most* people think you should read LotR before Silm, even though there are a lot of references in it that you won't understand unless you read Silm first. I imagine that in both cases, most people will enjoy reading the novel first, then the history...

Comment: Hm. When I first read the Silmarillion, I found Túrin's chapter the most frustrating part – not sure if it's more about its sheer length or the actual tragedy that is his story. In context it of course makes sense, and reading more of the Narn i Chîn Húrin afterwards did certainly provide interesting extra information. But would I have made it through if I hadn't read the Silmarillion before? I don't know. Anyway +1 for a valid opinion.

Comment: @Wade not sure that's a valid comparison though. In the LotR, the references are quite optional for grasping the story. The First Age is ancient history then, and everything you need to know about the Third is in the book itself. But the ongoings in the First age really don't make much sense without the present (or still-impactful-past) context. The Noldor's epic conflict has an overwhelming influence on all the three stories, but in each of them by itself the Silmaril must seem a _very_ quaint McGuffin Ex Machina.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Good point. I haven't actually read CoH yet :)

Comment: I have changed this to the accepted answer because I tend to agree with you the most. In fact, I don't even think it's necessary to read the introduction to the book, or any other mediating text; just to be willing to not understand all of the context.

Comment: I agree with this, to be honest the Children of hurin was my first tolkien book period and it worked rather nicely. I personally went: Children of hurin -> Silmarillion -> The hobbit -> LOTR -> unfinished tales -> fall of gondolin -> beren and luthien.

Answer (score 32):

### It is not *strictly necessary*, but it is recommended

*The Silmarillion* gives you an overview of the First Age. The Great Tales are stories that happen in the First Age, and they correspond to chapters in *The Silmarillion*.

The stories are not entirely self-contained, and *a lot* of reference is made to other events of Beleriand, which you'll be familiar with if you have read *The Silmarillion* first. That said, Christopher Tolkien attempts to compensate for this with a long preface and an glossary/index in the back.

It should also be noted that of the three Great Tales books, only *The Children of Húrin* is even a proper narrative story. The other two books are out-of-universe studies about their stories' respective external histories, showcasing a few different versions of the text to see how it evolved over time (similar to *The History of Middle-earth*). And as such I'd say that those other two books are significantly *more* difficult to read than *The Silmarillion*.

The essay "[A *Rings*-Reader's Bridge to the *Children of Húrin*](http://tolkien.slimy.com/essays/HurinBridge.html)" by Steuard Jenson may be of interest to you; it is designed for people who want to jump straight from *The Lord of the Rings* to *The Children of Húrin*.

And as a final note, this answer also applies to the two First Age stories inside *Unfinished Tales*, which are both just examples of Tolkien's Great Tales writings, and which reappear in those books.

Comment: @Wade - FWIW, while I would generally recommend Silm first, I think CoH is also a valid option, and being a traditional narrative it is an easier read. I would recommend reading both the link *and* Christopher's introduction though.

Comment: You convinced me. What about Unfinished Tales? Do you think it makes sense to read it before The Silm? + Do you think it should be read before or after Beren & Luthien and/or The Fall of Gondolin?

Comment: @Wade - I recommend people skip the first two tales of UT if they're planning to eventually read CoH and FoG. If you skip those and you've read the LotR appendices, then you can go directly to UT.

Comment: Unfortunately the _Bridge_ link is dead . . .

Comment: @m4r35n357 - I've reached out to the website owner about it, but in the meantime, [here's an archived link](http://web.archive.org/web/20230401145954/http://tolkien.slimy.com/essays/HurinBridge.html).

Comment: Thanks for that.  Admirably brief, and it works for me, but then I already know the story ;)

Comment: @m4r35n357 - the website is back up

Answer (score 10):

It depends on what you are looking for. If you just want to read a stand-alone story, you can read these as such. However, there's quite a bombardment of names and places, which may be confusing and overwhelming. If you want to know all the background and reasons leading up to the events in the stories, then you probably want to read *The Silmarillion* for context.

Specifically, you'll want to know a bit about... :

- The big bad guy, Morgoth.
- The Silmarils and the Doom of Mandos/Noldor.
- The rough geography of Beleriand (meaning the map in *The Silmarillion*).
- The Kingdoms of Doriath and Gondolin. Who founded them, where & why.
- Thingol and Melian.
- Finrod Felagund.
- The short story about Eöl and Aredhel is kind of essential background for The Fall of Gondolin, but also to learn where Túrin's infamous sword came from.

That being said, those reading *The Silmarillion* looking for fiction similar to *The Hobbit* or *Lord of the Rings* typically don't enjoy the book at all until they reach these stories. I remember disliking *The Silmarillion* during my first read until I got to the Beren & Luthien and Túrin stories. I would probably have been better off reading just those to begin with, then reading *The Silmarillion* later.

A good mind set for reading *The Silmarillion* is either that you want a history lesson about this fictional world, or that you like to read epic mythology similar to Norse or Greek mythology (the Poetic Edda, the Iliad etc).

Comment: A lot of people talking about this seem to avoid the simple "history book" explanation, perhaps they haven't really read it themselves ;).  FWIW my advice to anyone who wants to read the Silmarillion but can't get into it is to start from the "Of the Rings of Power" chapter and work backwards, chapter-wise.

Comment: @m4r35n357 The question here was "But is it really important to read The Silmarillion before you read The Children of Húrin, Beren and Lúthien and/or The Fall of Gondolin?" The Rings of Power have nothing to do with that.

Comment: I was commenting on your answer, not answering the message myself.  You mentioned the problems some people have reading the S, and I added a suggestion.